# Make wget use a password from file or use an encrypted password

Tags: unix, wget

We are using a deployment tool which has a script which downloads the artifact from the repository using wget with an ID/PWD and deploys that artifact to a particular location on Unix.

As far as its DEV/QA its fine to have the ID/PWD in the script. But if its prod, its actually risky to have it there.

Any solution for the same?

Comment: There is no solution for this. If you need the credentials, then you have to include the credentials. There is no such thing as an "encrypted password", there is no way to somehow magically hide the credentials. The question is: why would you have to?

Comment: Anyways got a solution.. I added them to the enviroment variables..

Comment: No idea why that should make any difference, they are still plain visible and accessible. But great that you solved your issue! Have fun!